# Getting a templated button's command to work

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I've used a control template to change the appearance of a button in a trivial way.  It now looks different, but does not behave like a button.  There are really two problems:

1. The button's command is never executed
2. After clicking on the button, it appears selected (i.e., the ellipse turns into an ugly blue rectangle)

Here's the general idea:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static commands:...}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding ...}"
                     .../>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that `Fill` was bound to a value that could be null. If the `Fill` brush is null rather than transparent, then there's nothing to click and the command doesn't get executed.  As Drew mentioned, with a solid fill, the button works correctly.

Takeaway lesson: if you want to hide your shape but still have it respond to user interaction, use a transparent brush, not a null brush.

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no reason this should be happening. I put together a test using ApplicationCommands.Copy and the command fired just fine. Could be your `CommandBinding` isn't working properly.
2. I also didn't see this based on copying your sample XAML and just setting `Fill="Green"`. You can try setting `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` on the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a custom templated button:

```
     <my:UniButton Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

The binding didn't work until adding a RelativeSource:

```
     <my:UniButton Command="{Binding MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:CustomPanel}}"/>
```

where     CustomPanel     is a control where my button lies.

Withal I had a simple button on the same panel, but it worked fine even without RelativeSource.